# Formula to track cumulative days away within a rolling 365 day period

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

As per the following example, [image: example] my known variables are my departure and return dates to a country. The 'days' column shows the number of days away on that specific trip, given by =(Return Date Cell - Departure Date Cell).

The column I am trying to populate is the number of days within the past 365 day period that I have been away from the country. This would be calculated using the return date, however it should be exclusive of the return and departure dates as those days count as being in the country.

The problem I'm struggling with when coming up with a formula in google sheets is it needs to accumulate all the days outside the country from the present day into the past, but it also needs to know when to 'stop counting' because it's out of that 365 day period.

In the example above, for row 4 (returns on 27/03/2022), it should not count the number of days from row 1 because the return date for row 1 was before 27/03/2021 (i.e. 365 days before).

Any ideas what I can do?

Comment: can you provide example of desired output in your F column?

Comment: also, end date of rolling 365 day period is todays date or last date from C column?

Answer (score 0):

This is the main formula you need to calculate the days of abstinence within the last 365 days.

```
IF(C2 < (TODAY() - 365); 0; IF(A2 >= TODAY() - 365; C2-A2; C2-TODAY()-365))
```

Explanation:

- return date is before `today - 365 days`? set the value to 0.

  - YES: set value to 0
  - NO: Check departure is later than `today - 365 days`?

    - YES: The whole abstinence was within the last 365 days. Set value to `return date` - `departure date`.
    - NO: Only parts of the abstinence are within the last 365 days. Set value to `today - 365 days` - `return date`.

Apply this formula to every row and then on the bottom of your table sum the whole column using `SUM()` and you will have the days of abstinence in the last 365 days.

[image: Google Sheet with formula applied]

Answer (score 0):

cell E2:

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(1/(1/DAYS(C2:C, A2:A))))
```

[image]

cell F2:

count days (within last 365 days since today)

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(1/(1/LEN(SUBSTITUTE(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(IF(DAYS(C2:C, A2:A)>=
 SEQUENCE(1, 500, ), A2:A+SEQUENCE(1, 500, ), )>=
 TODAY()-365, 1, )),,9^9)), " ", )))))
```

[image]

or if you don't count returnees

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(1/(1/LEN(SUBSTITUTE(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(IF(DAYS(C2:C, A2:A)>
 SEQUENCE(1, 500, ), A2:A+SEQUENCE(1, 500, ), )>=
 TODAY()-365, 1, )),,9^9)), " ", )))))
```

[image]

cumulative days (within last 365 days since today)

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(MMULT(TRANSPOSE((SEQUENCE(COUNTA(C2:C))<=
 SEQUENCE(1, COUNTA(C2:C)))*LEN(SUBSTITUTE(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(IF(
 DAYS(INDIRECT("C2:C"&COUNTA(C2:C)+1), INDIRECT("A2:A"&COUNTA(C2:C)+1))>
 SEQUENCE(1, 500, ), A2:A+SEQUENCE(1, 500, ), )>=
 TODAY()-365, 1, )),,9^9)), " ", ))), SEQUENCE(COUNTA(C2:C), 1, 1, 0)))
```

[image]

cumulative days (within last 365 days since latest return)

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(MMULT(TRANSPOSE((SEQUENCE(COUNTA(C2:C))<=
 SEQUENCE(1, COUNTA(C2:C)))*LEN(SUBSTITUTE(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(IF(
 DAYS(INDIRECT("C2:C"&COUNTA(C2:C)+1), INDIRECT("A2:A"&COUNTA(C2:C)+1))>
 SEQUENCE(1, 500, ), A2:A+SEQUENCE(1, 500, ), )>=
 MAX(C2:C)-365, 1, )),,9^9)), " ", ))), SEQUENCE(COUNTA(C2:C), 1, 1, 0)))
```

[image]

Comment: hi, the end date of the rolling 365 day period is the date in column C for that given row.  as an example: row 1 the period is between 19/01/2020 - 19/01/2020, so expected output is 30.
 row 2 the period is between 03/10/2020 - 03/10/2021, so expected output is 30+4=34 days.
 row 3 the period is between 05/11/2020 - 05/11/2021, so expected output is 30+4+5=39 days.  row 4 the period is between 27/03/2021 - 27/03/2022, so expected output is 4+5+4=13 days.

Comment: what do i do if my question hasn't been answered then

Comment: @jlibrar if none of these answers solved your issue I recon to go back to your question and rewrite it. include a better explanation of the issue, copy/sample of your sheet with an included example of the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include brackets as follows around last `TODAY()-365` to properly calculate number of days to include when trip occurs within TODAY date - 365:

```
IF(C2 < (TODAY() - 365); 0; IF(A2 >= TODAY() - 365; C2-A2; C2-(TODAY()-365)))
```